# When I use command [sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE] in my ubuntu server 20.04, I lose the ability to resolve websites

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router, iptables

Im trying to make a router out of ubuntu server for a class assignment. I've been looking at many guides to do so, most of which mention using the command from the title. Without the command, I cannot interact with anything behind the router like rdp or ssh. When the command is entered though, when I try [ping google.com] it will stall for a bit then tells me "ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution".

Im wondering what i can do that will allow traffic to pass through it like the original iptable command did without losing name resolution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just don't have MASQUERADE work on the lo interface. This confuses conntrack, and in the end replies don't match queries (I attempted to answer this, but seeing that a query from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.53 gets the source address changed to the IP address on the default interface has no explanation and probably depends on the kernel in use).

Comment: @A.B I'm a little lost by your comment. Are you just sharing some experience from your past or are you saying that by not specifying an interface, its applying to all of them, including lo interface which is causing my problems?

Comment: I'll make an answer, but I won't try and explain it, because it exposes possible bugs and that will go nowhere.

Comment: IIRC it has something to do with the fact that the `127.0.0.0/8` addresses are categorized as host-scope addresses, and masquerade is made not to use any of them for its job. I'm not entirely sure either whether it is intentional or a bug though.

Comment: It's probably not due to conntrack being confused either though. Rather it's the resolved stub ignoring such invalid traffic: `systemd-resolved[358]: Got packet on unexpected (i.e. non-localhost) IP range, ignoring.` (That *doesn't* mean an extra non-host-scope address listened by the stub *cannot* work as a DNS forwarder though.)

Comment: @TomYan conntrack turns source 127.0.0.1 into host's main IP address (eg into 192.0.2.2) for no good reason on my system (try this: `conntrack -E -d 127.0.0.0/8` and look at reply mappings). This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 5):

You are very certainly using `systemd-resolved` on your system as DNS cache. This can be checked by verifying that `/etc/resolv.conf` includes this entry:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

When one uses MASQUERADE with the `lo` interface, this confuses *conntrack* and replies from the DNS cache won't reach back correctly. Just don't use MASQUERADE on the `lo` interface.

Replace:

> ```
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
> ```

with:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o lo -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: yep! that did it! You're amazing, bless your heart. What Im curious about now though, is that another student I'm working on this with is using the same setup i am, did the same things I have (at least to our recollection) and hasn't had the same problem I had.

Comment: @KyleChampoux if this answer solved your problem, you should consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @A.B, upvoted. Your answer helped me greatly after spending hours troubleshooting why name resolution failed after enabling NAT on all interfaces. For my situation, I only needed NAT on one interface anyway so, rather than excluding `lo`, I just targeted a single interface: `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: @KyleChampoux I guess the other student, where it works without exploding lo, doesn't use systemd-resolved or any other local network service which listens on localhost/loopback interface?